# User-defined function for estimating coefficient of performance

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I am using hourly weather data to estimate performance of commercial refrigeration systems under various parameters. The formula for estimating co-efficient of performance (COP) of these systems is repeated for each hour.

I defined a formula to do this calculation:

```
Public Function estimatedCOP(dischargeTemp As Double, suctionTemp As Double)

Dim a As Double, b As Double, c As Double, d As Double, e As Double, f As Double

a = 9.12808037
b = 0.15059952
c = 0.00043975
d = -0.09029313
e = 0.00024061
f = -0.00099278

estimatedCOP = a + b * suctionTemp + c * suctionTemp * suctionTemp + _
    d * dischargeTemp + e * dischargeTemp * dischargeTemp + _
    f * suctionTemp * dischargeTemp

End Function
```

The function is repeated twice in a column with 8,760 rows (each hour of the year).

This gives the expected result, but takes a long time to calculate and update (as it's repeated ~17,000 times). **How can I improve the performance of this function?**

Comment: Hi, there are a few things that can probably be optimized in this function if appropriate. 1) use constants if the values of a-f if they are static. 2) provide a return type for the function, it is variant right now. That being said, those are pretty minor. This is just basic math ops, this should be fast (less than 1 second) for 10,000 items. What are you doing with the result of the function, writing it a worksheet? I suspect that might be where the slowdown is.

Comment: @RyanWildry it's used a in a column with 8760 rows.

Comment: Ahh, I gotcha. Try reworking the update as a sub and update the column by storing the results of the function to an array, then dump those values to the sheet in one shot. This should be faster.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `Double` data type for all variables. I think this is a good thing since it should avoid conversions. But it is probably too large for your purpose.

From the doc:

> Double (double-precision floating-point)  8 bytes
>     -1.79769313486231E308 to -4.94065645841247E-324 for negative values

Source: [Data type summary](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary)

Perhaps using the `single` data type is enough ?

> Single (single-precision floating-point)  4 bytes     -3.402823E38 to
>   -1.401298E-45 for negative values
>   1.401298E-45 to 3.402823E38 for positive values

You can try and compare results.

For reference a response I made on another topic, that includes comments about data types: [Adding qty If duplicates keys found VBA](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/240534/219060)

---

It is unfortunate that the variable names (a..f) are not descriptive and 
**meaningful**. That makes logic errors harder to spot since the variables look  all the same. Surely all those values have a meaning ?

---

Something else: if you are doing calculations in a loop and assuming this is in Excel, you can **suspend automatic recalculation** at the beginning of your procedure:

```
Application.Calculation = xlManual
```

Turn it back on when you are done:

```
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the number of operations from 5 additions, 8 multiplications to 5 additions, 5 multiplications using this (incorporating the advice to use constants, declared at module level):

```
    Const a = 9.12808037
    Const b = 0.15059952
    Const c = 0.00043975
    Const d = -0.09029313
    Const e = 0.00024061
    Const f = -0.00099278
    
    Public Function estimatedCOP(dischargeTemp As Double, suctionTemp As Double)
    '    estimatedCOP = a + b * suctionTemp + c * suctionTemp * suctionTemp + _
    '        d * dischargeTemp + e * dischargeTemp * dischargeTemp + _
    '        f * suctionTemp * dischargeTemp
    
        estimatedCOP = (e * dischargeTemp + d + f * suctionTemp) * dischargeTemp + (c * suctionTemp + b) * suctionTemp + a
    End Function
```

Optimization like this nearly always looks ugly. That's why I've left the original formula as a comment.